# Satis Installation & Usage Guide for Beginner

Tags: php, composer-php, satis

I am new to Satis and I have tried with some tutorials such as https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-a-local-mirror-for-composer-packages-with-satis--net-36726. But their explanation is very blur and incomplete.

This is what I have done.

1. I created new empty folder.
2. I run composer on that folder with the command `composer create-project composer/satis --stability=dev`
3. Now I see in the folder contain a folder called "satis". Inside that folder I see "bin", "src", "test", and "views" folder. Also, there are "compser.json" and "composer.lock" files.

So, what should I do now? I don't find any "satis.json" as on getcomposer.org tutorial. I really stuck there and don't know how to go forward. Why is it install a "Satis" folder in the folder I run? Does that mean, I have to install Satis on every project I need to use it? If you know how, please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is your task to create that `satis.json` (or whatever name you like), fill it with the content you need, and then run the Satis command to create the repository.

The configuration has many variables that cannot be guessed beforehand, but that have to be filled by you because you know the details of how you are hosting the Satis repository.

You cannot break anything. Satis runs on it's own, creates some files, and then is finished. You can run it any amount of times to learn how to tweak it and make it work for you.

Comment: Hi Sven. Thanks a lot for your answer. I have created my satis.json file. When I tried to run `php ./satis/bin/satis build ./satis.json ./packages-mirror`, it says "You must set up the project dependencies, run the following commands:
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php". I already have composer installed on my PC before, do I need to install another copy on my PC? Should I uninstall the original one before installing it here?

Comment: You should probably go into that `satis` folder where the `composer.lock` file is, and run `composer install` to fetch the dependencies of Satis. After that, I'd expect Satis to work.